# How to use an getter method as a property when I json_encode a Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For example, in the class

```
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity
 */
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var int The id
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $name;


    public function getRandomNumber()
    {
        return rand();
    }
}
```

When I call the `json_encode()` with this entity, it not bring the `getRandomNumber()` value as an property of the class.

I would like it returns:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "randomNumber": 123456
}
```

But it returns:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use JMSSerializer bundle!
I use it in all my websites, and it is really a great solution.
https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer
It uses annotations, and creates json-serialized entities. It takes attributes values of your entity, but with a specific annotation @Accessor, it uses the specified getter to get his value.
For example:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;

/**
 * @Expose
 * @Accessor("getRandomNumber")
 */
public $randomNumber;

public function getRandomNumber(){
    return rand();
}
```

Comment: The best: you can deserialize a previously JMSserialized entity, and so, retrieve your entity as an object!

Comment: I didn't knew this bundle, it's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` will return a JSON object with the public properties of the object passed to it. If you want to include `randomNumber` you could make it a public property and set it in the constructor like

```
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity
 */
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var int The id
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $randomNumber;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->randomNumber = $this->getRandomNumber();
    }

    public function getRandomNumber()
    {
        return rand();
    }
}
```

For more complex serialization of objects you might want to look at [the symfony serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: Thank you mickadoo, but I cannot do this solution because i'll use it to return the possibles transactions in my state machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the interface [`\JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) to specify data which should be serialized to JSON:

```
class Example implements \JsonSerializable
{
    // ...

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        // mixed data which can be serialized by json_encode() 
        return array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'randomNumber' => $this->getRandomNumber(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you yceruto, it certainly solves my the problem, the downside is remember to update this method the Entity if some new fields is add

Answer (score 1):

Use the virtual property

Info: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty

```
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity
 */
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var int The id
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="string")
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     */
    public function getRandomNumber()
    {
        return rand();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't knew this bundle, it's exactly what I was looking for. Your solution as @Dujardin Emmanuel does the job